# copy shares permissions after serveur migration

Tags: permissions, share, robocopy

Deal all,

i am about to migrate a production server (mainly files and scheduled tasks),

the old one is a windows 2000 server and the new one is a windows 2008 R2 VM.

i have already set up the exact hard disk drives schema on the targeted server (Win2008).

i would be gratefull if someone would advise me on the easiest way to ''copy '' shared folder permissions from the old server to the new one; 
that is to say; i would like users who had rights to any shared folder to keep them when the new one (VM with Win 2008) would be online and the old server (win 2000) would be decommissioned.

Please note that, unfortunately, so far none of the robocopy suggested answers found on this forum answered my need.

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

best solution is here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/125996

this may be helpfull as well:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/46d8d9db-8e21-498d-a998-6df2c8394364/how-to-migrate-share-and-share-permissions?forum=winserverMigration

Thank you.